# Is it possible to add Windows.Devices libraries into the WinForm Application?

Tags: c#, uwp

Is it possible to add Universal Windows liblaries into the C# Winforms Project like below lib?

```
using Windows.Devices;
```

Thanks

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#IJjAvoQyqwq05qsg.97

Answer (score 1):

You can reference UWP libraries manually in non-UWP project as well. The most up-to-date guide on this is [in Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).

In short - you need to reference appropriate `winmd` libraries from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\`.

- **System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime** - C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5
- **System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml** - C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5
- **System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime** - C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5
- **Windows.winmd** - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade
- **Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd** - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract
- **Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd** - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract